# Why doesn't this update my state, it should? React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a function that updates state, and I've used simular functions to update the same that that works fine, but this for some reason doesn't update the state... I've stared myself blind on this problem..
Here is the call from the reducer (until this point everything works correctly)

```
case 'UI_CONTROLL_SUCCESS':
    {
      if(action.answer.controllType)
      state = changeUi(state, action.answer.questionId, action.answer.answerId, action.answer.controllValue, action.answer.controllType);
      else
      return state
    }
```

It calls the function. Here's the function it calls:

```
function changeUi(project, questionId, answerId, newValue, whatUi)
{
  console.log(newValue);
  return project.map(item => {
    if(item._id != questionId) {
      return item;
    } else {
      return {...item, answers: item.answers.map(answer => {
          if(answer._id != answerId) {
            return answer
        } else if(answer._id == answerId) {
          if(whatUi == "setAnswerVisibility"){
            return updateObject(answer, { visibility : newValue })}
          else if (whatUi == "setAnswerDisabled"){
            return updateObject(answer, { disabled: newValue })}
          else if (whatUi == "SetAnswerValue"){
            return updateObject(answer, { value: newValue })
          }
          else{
            return answer
          }
        }
        else{
          return answer
        }
      })
    }}
    console.log(item);
  })
}
```

All values in the parameters that gets sent from the action{} are correct. So the function get's the right information.

a mongoDB Schema of the document that lives inside the state(I don't include all props, only the relevant.):

```
var questionModel = new Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    qpId: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    answers: [answerModel],
    description: String
});

var answerModel = new Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    questionId: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    answerText: String,
    value: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    settings: settingsModel,
    });


var settingsModel = new Schema({
    disabled: Boolean, 
    answerType: String,
    visibility: Boolean,
    setVisibilityPaths:[{_id:false, questionId: Schema.Types.ObjectId, answerId: Schema.Types.ObjectId}],
    setDisabledPaths: [{_id:false, questionId: Schema.Types.ObjectId, answerId: Schema.Types.ObjectId}],
    setAnswerValue:[{_id:false, questionId: Schema.Types.ObjectId, answerId: Schema.Types.ObjectId, answerValue: Schema.Types.Mixed}],
    setAnswerVisibility: Boolean,
    setAnswerDisabled: Boolean
}, {id: false});
```

Comment: Delimit your `if` and `else` statements' body with brackets (`{...}`) and you'll see the problem.

Comment: I did but i still don't see the problem :/

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not returning state

```
case 'UI_CONTROLL_SUCCESS':
    {
      if(action.answer.controllType)
      return changeUi(state, action.answer.questionId, action.answer.answerId, action.answer.controllValue, action.answer.controllType);
      else
      return state
    }
```

Comment: Yeah that was a stupid mistake but it still doesn't work :/ It's not rerendering the changes

Comment: add state you passed in function changeUi(state

Comment: please console your state and post it

Comment: You won't get smarter by that, it's huge. Also there is some sensitive information there. The app i'm working on is only being accessable of a limited amount of people

Answer (score 0):

If you're not returning please return the new state inside the if condition.

```
case 'UI_CONTROLL_SUCCESS':
    {
      if(action.answer.controllType)
       return {...state, ...changeUi(state, action.answer.questionId, action.answer.answerId, action.answer.controllValue, action.answer.controllType)};
      else
      return state
    }
```

**Don't mutate the state by assigning the changeUi function return values to state**

Comment: Yeah that was a stupid mistake thanks, but it still doesn't work :/ It's not rerendering the changes

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, it was a durp mistake, i tried to change answer.disabled but it should be answer.settings.disabled...

But thanks for reminding me about the immutable object thing :)
cheers!